# How to investigate down sessions in Windows Terminal Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

I've got a problem on a Windows Terminal Server (2003 R2): after having launched a particular application and disconnected from TSE, the session is left on the server with the 'Down' state.

I'm not able to kill that session and the only process remaining is csrss.exe (which I can't kill).

The application is the Cygwin X server. I don't know what is done by the application to trigger that problem.

What can cause a 'Down' state? How to investigate why a session is left in this state? What tools would you recommend? I have seen nothing related in the event viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following Citrix forum thread [Down Sessions: caused by NX Client 3.0.0.68](http://forums.citrix.com/message.jspa?messageID=667855#667855) as that mentions a problem and solution with Cygwin.

According to this Tech Republic article [Terminal Services Manager under Windows Server 2003](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-5208163.html) a down session state is:

> Down—This state indicates that the
>   session could not be initialized or
>   terminated.

As far as I can tell this is can be caused by application crashing or not terminating properly.

There also appear to be hotfixes available relating to csrss.exe not responding as per another [Citrix forum thread](http://forums.citrix.com/message.jspa?messageID=1386285#1386285).

Comment: This might be worth contacting Microsoft support about.

Comment: math, how did you fix the problem in the end?